# How to restrict/deny data access to an application system administrator

Tags: web-applications, software-design, administrator, cloud-security

Let's take this example:

We have subscribed to a cloud infrastructure (IaaS) platform. On top of it we had built an software application and hosted it on the platform which becomes the centralized access point for all the end users.

Now we are the typical administrator/ owner of that application hosted in the platform. In this scenario, is there any way to deny/restrict data access for the application administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is encrypted (what it should be), the solution would be to not have access to the users encryption keys.

As long as you, as the sites administrators, do not have access to the users keys, you should not be able to see their data.